# cut not outputting anything

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cut-command

I created a script by using the command line initially:

```
grep -c "Author" reviews_folder/* | cut -d \/ -f 2 | sort -nt':' -k2 | sed 's/.dat:/ /g'
```

It worked, however I then needed to make it a shell script which allowed the user to enter a directory for it to search, so I changed it to:

```
grep -c "Author" $1/* | cut -d \/ -f 2 | sort -nt':' -k2 | sed 's/.dat:/ /g'
```

After this was complete, rather than the script working, it just printed lots of blank lines.

Comment: Add an `echo $1` to see what's going on, and any spaces in the directory names?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are running your script like: `script.sh dir/` or `bash script.sh dir/`.

The way you pass the directory is causing the problem.

In your script you got a `grep` command:

```
grep -c "Author" $1/*
```

If you pass the directory with tailing slash, the `grep` command would be run as:

```
grep -c "Author" dir//*
```

Example:

```
grep -c "Author" dir//somefile.dat dir//someother-file.dat
```

And its result would be similar to:

```
dir//somefile.dat:5
```

And your `cut` command would only return an empty string and pass it to `sort`:

```
dir//somefile.dat:5   # < You are asking for second part which is empty
```

So either run your script like: `script.sh dir` or change it to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=${1%/}
grep -c "Author" ${DIR}/* | cut -d \/ -f 2 | sort -nt':' -k2 | sed 's/.dat:/ /g'
```